# PHP 5.2 Function needed for GENERIC sorting FOLLOWUP

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

OK, you guys gave me a great solution for sorting a recordset array last Friday. ([PHP 5.2 Function needed for GENERIC sorting of a recordset array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884325/php-5-2-function-needed-for-generic-sorting-of-a-recordset-array))

But now when I implement it, I end up with an extra element in the recordset array. I won't wast space reposting the same info, as the link is above. But the bottom line is that when I sort an array of 5 records, the resulting array has 6 records. The last element in the array is not a record array, but rather just a element containing an integer value of 1. I presume that it is somehow getting the output value of the "strnatcasecmp" function, but I have no idea how it is happening.

Here is the function that you fine folks provided last week:

```
function getSortCommand($field, $sortfunc) {
    return create_function('$var1, $var2', 'return '.$sortfunc.'($var1["'.$field.'"], $var2["' .$field .'"]);');
}
```

And here is the line I am calling to sort the array:

```
$trek[] = usort($trek, getSortCommand('name', 'strnatcasecmp'));
```

This produces the following output, with an extra element tacked on to the end.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => Kirk
        [shirt] => Gold
        [assign] => Bridge
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => McCoy
        [shirt] => Blue
        [assign] => Sick Bay
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => Scotty
        [shirt] => Red
        [assign] => Engineering
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [name] => Spock
        [shirt] => Blue
        [assign] => Bridge
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [name] => Uhura
        [shirt] => Red
        [assign] => Bridge
    )

[5] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do

```
usort($trek, getSortCommand('name', 'strnatcasecmp'));
```

[`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) returns a boolean indicating whether it was executed successfully (it sorts the elements in place):

> **Return Values**
>
> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

By doing `$trek[] = usort(...)`, you append the result of the function to the array.

Comment: Ahhh, so you are saying this was a classic PEBKAC issues. (Problem Exists Between Keyboard and Chair) Thank you.